# magnesium citrate to carbonate conversion - for oral consumption?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I've been instructed to drink a 10-oz bottle of magnesium citrate saline solution, which label says has about 17.5g mag citrate in it. (1.74g/fl oz)

I prefer to make my own solution using a powdered product called Natural Calm, which has "350mg mangnesum (as magnesium carbonate)" per serving (2 tsp). (It also has citric acid to make mag citrate in water - https://www.naturalvitality.com/products-naturalcalm-unflavored)

What's the roughly equivalent amount of the mag carbonate powder to get 10oz of mag citrate solution?

thank you!

Comment: 1 tsp is not an exact unit.

Comment: Requests for medical advises are explicitly off-topic on Chemistry SE site. The best if you ask your physician if you can replace the drink by your formula and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's **Magnesium** you are after, the *molecular weight* of magnesium citrate (C6H6MgO7) is 214, and magnesium carbonate (MgCO3) is 84.  Magnesium has a weight of 24.

84/214 × 17.5 g = 6.87 g magnesium carbonate

6.87 g x 24g Mg/84g MgCO3 x 2 tsp/.350 **grams** Mg = 11.2 tsp !

This will give you the same amount of magnesium as the 17.5 g magnesium citrate in the entire 10 oz bottle and possibly a burp or two.

However, if a **doctor** or any other medical professional **instructed** magnesium citrate, **please** follow their instructions and discuss the matter with them **before** doing anything else.

Comment: Thanks so much Robert. Despite what I said, this is not for a medical procedure. Self-administered cleanse.